# DVD or Bluray editing tool

Tags: dvd, bluray

I'm looking for a tool that can create a DVD or a BluRay from a set of Movies, files etc..

The most important functionality for the tool should be that it could add a button to the menu that can open an URL outside of the actual disk.

Answer (score 2):

I regularly use [Sony DVD Architect](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/fr/dvdastudio) for building complex DVD (as well as simple, it's quite intuitive) like commercials ones. DVD Architect is compatible with Blu-Ray, but doesn't include advanced features like BD live and other. From the same editor with a similar ergonomy, you can use [DoStudio](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/fr/dostudio).

There are two editions:

- DoStudio Ex: expensive but complete,
- DoStudio Indie: more cheap but I don't know if it includes the functions you want.

You cannot build a complex BD/DVD without expensive software. A DVD cannot point to an URL of any type (unless it's inside the disc like a video/photo/music/...) and a BD can use the BD Live and BD touch functionalities to open web pages on any Blu-Ray player connected to internet. I think there is some limitations: you can maybe open videos with BD Live, but web pages have limited HTML/CSS and other support.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reach a URL from either. And Blu-ray is always better than DVD given the fact the DVD is by nature Standard Definition. Why not just produce digital files?

Comment: Can you make a clickable link in a digital file?

Comment: Yes there are a few ways to do this... what exactly are you looking to do?